# How to manage the database in an environment per branch, creating a new instance per branch is the best approach?

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, flyway

I'm trying to create an environment per branch using Git lab CI, until here we're good. But my concern right now is how to manage the Database?

I thought of using RDS and terraform, but what I'm doing is basically creating and destroying an RDS instance and recreating it from the final snapshot to a new RDS Instance. I wonder if this is the best way of doing this or do you recommend another approach?

Comment: I personally like one of the suggestions that is depicted in one of the answers and I heard during a conversation, i.e. flyway.